# How to use ein/eine in any sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

I am a spanish speaker but I'm learning german from english. I am learning german by myself and it is a little hard. I am using http://www.memrise.com/ to learn german. The method to learn by repeat the words is good. But I want to learn the grammatical part or the correct way to make a sentence, and my question is,  when I have to use ein or eine in the sentences?

Comment: This question is a bit broad. Could you specify what exactly you are aiming for? Is this about gender, or about definite/indefinite articles, or about word order, or anything else? For example, what would be your analogous answer to the question "When do you have to use *un*/*una* in a Spanish sentence?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell...

Both *ein* and *eine* are articles, indefinite articles, as *a* and *an* in English, but unlike English, you have to use them with gender concordance. In German nouns might be, as in Spanish, masculine or feminine, but unlike Spanish, also neutral. Unlike Spanish, German has also an extra coordinate called *case* (Fall or Kasus). The case can be *nominative, genitive, dative* or *accusative*. You won't *fully* soon all that what *case* conveys, so don't worry if you don't understand all by now.

You use:

- **ein** as the indefinite article for nominative neutral or masculine nouns. Or as accusative indefinite article of a neutral name.
- **eine** is the indefinite article for feminine nouns in accusative, feminine.

Answer (score 4):

Eine is used for feminine nouns:

> Das ist eine Katze. (Esta es una gata.)

Ein is used for masculine and neuter nouns:

> Das ist ein Auto (nt). (Este es un coche.)
>
> Das ist ein Hund(m). (Este es un perro.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Vielleicht noch sagen, dass es der unbestimmte Artikel ist (im Ggs. zum bestimmten (der, die, das)).